# Product of common entities of a dataframe and a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Can somebody suggest me the most pythonic and efficient approach for the below requirement.

I have a panda's dataframe (d1) as below:

```
    jam      lam     mam  pam  qam  sam  uam  wam
0    1     1.30103    1    1    1    1    1    1

0 is the id
```

And, a dictionary (d2):

```
{u'bam': 1.0,
 u'ham': 1.0,
 u'jam': 0.82390874094431876,
 u'kam': 1.0,
 u'lam': 1.0,
 u'mam': 0.82390874094431876,
 u'pam': 1.0,
 u'ram': 1.0,
 u'sam': 0.82390874094431876,
 u'tam': 1.0}
```

My requirement is simple, to multiply the common entities.

```
Example Lam->1.30103 of d1 will be multiplied to lam->(1.0) of d2
```

The output that I expect is a dataframe (somewhat like below):

```
    jam      lam     mam      pam  qam  sam    uam  wam
0    0     1.30103  0.82390    1    0   0.82    0    0
```

Only lam, mam, pam and sam have values because they are common entities in both d1 and d2. Also their corresponding values are multiplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd construct a df from the dict, multiply them and then select the cols from d1 again:

```
In [107]:
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2, orient='index').T
df2

Out[107]:
   tam       sam  ram  bam       mam  pam  lam  kam       jam  ham
0    1  0.823909    1    1  0.823909    1    1    1  0.823909    1

In [114]:
(df * df2)[df.columns].fillna(0)

Out[114]:
        jam      lam       mam  pam  qam       sam  uam  wam
0  0.823909  1.30103  0.823909    1    0  0.823909    0    0
```